# static_assert of class template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, assert, static-assert

Can I do the following to check that class template integer parameter is even:

```
template<int N>
struct S
{
     static_assert( N % 2 == 0, "fail" );
};
```

This compiles with gcc 4.8.3, but I am not sure if this code does not violate C++11 standard, and if it is going to work with other standard-compliant compilers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @chris yes, it is: "fail"

Comment: @jrok, are you saying that it is Ok, or not Ok?

Comment: @user2052436 I'm playing grammar police :) The code is ok.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're link ain't correct

Comment: @P0W Sorry, it's this one: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/zUE

Comment: @user2052436 _'... going to work with other standard-compliant compilers ...`_ [I've been trying your sample here](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/zUE), and the result seems pretty ridiculous for me :P. Wait a minute or two, I'm downloading VS2013 Express, to check it now. I'm not really trusting this online VS2013 service yet :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real requirement of using `static_assert` is that the expression used must be a constant expression (i.e. the value must be determinable at compile-time), so you will run into an issue if you attempt to use a value that is not known until run-time.

So as long as the values you use are compile-time constants you should be fine.